# Hide Icon from the label of QComboBox

Tags: c++, qt, pyqt4, qcombobox

I am trying to implement a `QComboBox`, which holds `QIcon` and `QString`, like this:

```
QComboBox.addItem(icon, label);
```

I want the icons to be visible in the drop-down list, but not in the toolbar. Only the string should be visible after item selection.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Easy (but a bit hackish): reimplement `showPopup` and `hidePopup`, and add/remove the icons as necessary.

Comment: @ekhumoro That may not work for my scenario, as in either case, I don't want the icon to be visible in the toolbar. If I implement in showPopup, the prev selection will display the icon in the toolbar, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to set a delegate and to draw the items yourself.
Then you can choose when or not to draw the icon ( decorationRole ), you can choose not to draw the icon for the index which is the current index.
I could find a quick example on how to use a delegate on combobox:
http://programmingexamples.net/wiki/Qt/Delegates/ComboBoxDelegate

But I am afraid it is not the most easist of the ways.
Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

To solve this problem, it is enough to override the paintEvent method, taking the default implementation from the sources. Before drawing control `QStyle::CE_ComboBoxLabel`, it is necessary to set an invalid value of the `QStyleOptionComboBox.currentIcon`

This works well if the combobox is not editable, otherwise there is an empty space on the left side intended for drawing the icon. Looking at the source, I found out that the combobox changes the geometry of the `QLineEdit`. If the current element has an icon then geometrically `QLineEdit` will shift to the right. In order to prevent this in the same paintEvent, it is necessary to force the geometry of `QLineEdit` without taking into account the icon.

The following code takes this into account and works well in both modes:

```
class ComboBox : public QComboBox {
public:
    ComboBox(QWidget *parent = nullptr)
        : QComboBox(parent) {  }

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *) override {
        QStylePainter painter(this);
        painter.setPen(palette().color(QPalette::Text));

        // draw the combobox frame, focusrect and selected etc.
        QStyleOptionComboBox opt;
        initStyleOption(&opt);
        painter.drawComplexControl(QStyle::CC_ComboBox, opt);

        // draw the icon and text
        opt.currentIcon = QIcon();
        if (auto le = lineEdit()) {
            le->setGeometry(style()->subControlRect(QStyle::CC_ComboBox, &opt, QStyle::SC_ComboBoxEditField, this));
        } else {
            painter.drawControl(QStyle::CE_ComboBoxLabel, opt);
        }
    }
};
```