# QComboBox: Only show the icons when expanded

Tags: c++, qt, qcombobox

Starting from a "normal" `QCombobox`

[image]

I'd like to get a `QCombobox` that only shows the icon when it's expanded, but not when it's collapsed.

[image]

I've found several answers to similar questions, but all of them show code for much more complex situations and I have not managed to distill the core of it.

There are two approaches I've seen: attaching a `QListView` or using a `QItemDelegate` (or both).

But I could not find any sample code that is straight to the point.

This is my *starting* point:

```cpp
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    ui->iconsComboBox->addItem(QIcon(":/icons/1.png"), "red");
    ui->iconsComboBox->addItem(QIcon(":/icons/2.png"), "green");
    ui->iconsComboBox->addItem(QIcon(":/icons/3.png"), "pink");

    auto quitAction = new QAction();
    quitAction->setShortcuts(QKeySequence::Quit);
    addAction(quitAction);
    connect(quitAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(close()));
}
```

The full working code at that stage is here: https://github.com/aoloe/cpp-qt-playground-qcombobox/tree/simple-qcombobox

How can I hide the icon when the QCombobox is closed?

---

I have accepted the two pull requests by eyllanesc:

- [A solution extending QComboBox](https://github.com/aoloe/cpp-qt-playground-qcombobox/tree/QProxyStyle)
- [A solution using QProxyStyle](https://github.com/aoloe/cpp-qt-playground-qcombobox/tree/override-QComboBox-paintEvent)

You can get the code and run it to see it in action.

Comment: The most similar question I've found, is probably [Hide Icon from the label of QComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45546155/hide-icon-from-the-label-of-qcombobox), but the question is a bit vague and the only answer is not really encouraging (and points to a dead link).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution is to override the paintEvent method:

```
##ifndef COMBOBOX_H
#define COMBOBOX_H

#include <QComboBox>
#include <QStylePainter>

class ComboBox : public QComboBox
{
public:
    using QComboBox::QComboBox;
protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
    {
        QStylePainter painter(this);
        painter.setPen(palette().color(QPalette::Text));
        // draw the combobox frame, focusrect and selected etc.
        QStyleOptionComboBox opt;
        initStyleOption(&opt);
        opt.currentIcon = QIcon();
        opt.iconSize = QSize();
        painter.drawComplexControl(QStyle::CC_ComboBox, opt);
        // draw the icon and text
        painter.drawControl(QStyle::CE_ComboBoxLabel, opt);
    }

};

#endif // COMBOBOX_H
```

and if you want to use it in the .ui then you must [promote it](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-using-custom-widgets.html).

---

Another possible solution is to use a QProxyStyle

```cpp
#ifndef COMBOBOXPROXYSTYLE_H
#define COMBOBOXPROXYSTYLE_H

#include <QProxyStyle>

class ComboBoxProxyStyle : public QProxyStyle
{
public:
    using QProxyStyle::QProxyStyle;
    void drawControl(QStyle::ControlElement element, const QStyleOption *opt, QPainter *p, const QWidget *w) const
    {
        if(element == QStyle::CE_ComboBoxLabel){
            if (const QStyleOptionComboBox *cb = qstyleoption_cast<const QStyleOptionComboBox *>(opt)) {
                QStyleOptionComboBox cb_tmp(*cb);
                cb_tmp.currentIcon = QIcon();
                cb_tmp.iconSize = QSize();
                QProxyStyle::drawControl(element, &cb_tmp, p, w);
                return;
            }
        }
        QProxyStyle::drawControl(element, opt, p, w);
    }
};

#endif // COMBOBOXPROXYSTYLE_H
```

```cpp
ui->iconsComboBox->setStyle(new ComboBoxProxyStyle(ui->iconsComboBox->style()));
```

Comment: thanks @eyllanesc for your answer. i'm not sure that this is the simplest solution. i'm currently exploring the usage of `QItemDelegate` and will later try to use a custom `ComboBox` as you suggest and come back and tell how it worked out.

Comment: @a.l.e I have made a PR to your repo so you can easily test it. The QItemDelegate only serves to modify the popup that clearly will not solve your problem.